# parallel_coordinates KeyError when reading CSV with headers

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-coordinates

I am reading in a CSV file with headers - this:

```
df = pd.read_csv("label-evolution.csv")

print(df)
```

2021    2022           Name
0   2909    8915    a
1   2027    5088        b
2  12530   29232         c
3    842    2375       a
4  11238   23585   b
5   6961   20533           c
6   1288    4246          d
7  13808   33186          e
8   3360    8847      e
9   7360   16830       f

If I then do:
`parallel_coordinates(df,'Name')`

I get a KeyError on 'Name'.

However, if I do this after reading in the CSV, I get no such error, and all works fine.

```
df = pd.read_csv("label-evolution.csv")
df.columns=["Nov/Dec 2021","Nov/Dec 2022","Name"]
print(df)
```

My question is:
How do I get the csv file header to work in the expected way, and, as a subsidiary question, what is going on such that the first method produces an error?

I tried the first method, which produced the error.

I found the work-around, which gave the right result, but I would like to read headers straight from the csv